# axis.text margins in ggplot2 2.0.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've just updated ggplot2 to 2.0.0 and have run into a problem with replacing some deprecated code. When I make graphs it is my preference to set the ticks pointing inwards, so I would go about it like so:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

p + theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 21)) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm"), axis.ticks.margin = unit(0.5, "cm"))
```

This no longer works, because:

```
Warning message:
`axis.ticks.margin` is deprecated. Please set `margin` property  of `axis.text` instead
```

Without the margin the tick labels are overlapping with the panel border. I had assumed that I should now replace that last line with something like this:

```
theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm")) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, unit = "cm")))
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything, and I'm now a bit stuck. Help would be greatly appreciated!